# Loadstring, como usar?

Tags: lua

Estou usando a função loadstring, mas não sei se essa é a maneira correta:

```
a= "st = {b=1, c=2}"
st = {}
b = loadstring(a)
b()
print(st.b)
```

Há algum modo mais simples?

Comment: Depende do que você chama de mais simples. Se eu entendi, não existe. Por que existiria?

Comment: Com mais simples eu quis dizer menos poluido.
Fiz assim:
st = "{b=1, c=2}"
st = "st="..st
st loadstring(st)
print(st.b)

Comment: Em exemplos artificiais assim, é complicado dizer o que pode ser menos poluído. Por exemplo `print(1)` produz o mesmo resultado neste caso e é menos poluído. Dá para fazer coisas intermediárias mas aí é questão de gosto já que este não é um problema real.

Comment: Sim, mas a forma mais prática de usar o LoadString, qual é?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você não precisar criar a variável global `st`, use

```
b = loadstring("return {b=1, c=2}")()
```

Se você quiser fazer isso muitas vezes, considere algo como

```
function eval(x)
  return loadstring("return "..x)()
end
```

Comment: Ah, a grande magica é o return. Obrigado!